# Does a different site architecture in international subdirectories hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, internationalization, subdirectory

I have a top level domain `example.com`, it's a site for the US already well positioned.

The business is expanding to EU and we are going to create subdirectories to use the DA of example.com. Like: `www.example.com/es`, `www.example.com/de`, etc

The services offered differ greatly and therefore the EU subdirectories and the `.com` domain are going to have a different site architecture

Does it affect my positioning if the site architecture of the subdirectories is different?

Comment: Using subdomains instead of subdirectories may be a better way to keep each country a bit more separated. A subdomain gives Google a clearer idea that "this is separate" than a subfolder, allowing you to optimize each subdomain for its particular country and language, versus mixing them all in www.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I was also contemplating that option. It's going to be cheaper, and most importantly we won't need to build everything from scratch. The subdirectories will benefit from the current DA instantly. My only concern is the site architecture. I've been researching and all the sites operating under subdirectories keep the same site architecture.